# Time Complexity of Generic Traversal of Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree, time-complexity

Algorithm:

```
Tour (node t)
if t is a leaf node
    visit t
else
    visit t
    Tour(t.left)
    visit t
    Tour(t.right)
    visit t
```

Is the complexity of the code above O(n)? ;where n is the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each node is visited once with constant access time.  I'm assuming that you meant just one `visit` in the else clause, not 3.  This makes more sense to me:

```
Tour (node t)
    visit t
    if t is a leaf node
        return
    Tour(t.left)
    Tour(t.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: What is your visit t operation ?

If your visit t operation is a constant time operation and does not depend on input size n then this algorithms' overall time complexity is O(n).